# Raspbian Stretch read/only

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, fstab

My system is based upon Raspbian Stretch and has three partitions:

1. boot (fat32)
2. rootfs (ext4)
3. home (ext4)

I don't have a lot of background services, just samba, ssh, lighttpd. 
I'm looking for a recommended way to mount the second partition as read-only.

Most guides I find are related to Jessie and they refer to outdated files.
I'm able to mount the partition as ro, but I don't know what should I do with logging and the other system features that need to write to disk.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this guide to work with Stretch 2017-11-29:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=161416

A few notes, though:

In the second code block, there is no "local-bottom" directory to copy, which is also noted by posts below the original.  This is fine, and you don't need an "overlay-bottom" directory for it to work.

In the third code block, be sure to scroll down and modify/add every line that differs, not just the top 4, which get commented.  This is where I really got into trouble when I made mistakes.

Below, I have copied the block and marked modified lines (m) and added lines (a).

```
m#   if [ "${readonly}" = "y" ]; then
        roflag=-r
m#   else
m#       roflag=-w
m#   fi

    # FIXME This has no error checking
    modprobe ${FSTYPE}

    checkfs ${ROOT} root

    # FIXME This has no error checking
    # Mount root
a    mkdir /upper /lower
    if [ "${FSTYPE}" != "unknown" ]; then
m        mount ${roflag} -t ${FSTYPE} ${ROOTFLAGS} ${ROOT} /lower
    else
m        mount ${roflag} ${ROOTFLAGS} ${ROOT} /lower
    fi
a    modprobe overlay
a    mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /upper
a    mkdir /upper/data /upper/work
a    mount -t overlay \
a        -olowerdir=/lower,upperdir=/upper/data,workdir=/upper/work \
a        overlay ${rootmnt}
```

If you're curious about what's happening beneath, this document provided a reasonable explanation for me: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt

Answer (score 1):

I forked some existing scripts to easily setup a read-only root filesystem on a fresh install of the raspbian stretch dist.

With a single paste of commands from the README, everything will be configured and the Pi will reboot into read-only mode.

Two simple .sh scripts are placed in /root. One to reboot in to permanent-write mode (disable read-only mode permanently) and one to enable read-only permanently.

Get the script here: https://github.com/JasperE84/root-ro